# RequiredAttribute depending on Parent-Property-Attributes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, required, model-validation

For my asp.net mvc 5 application I use some more or less complex and nested models.

So I have a model class:

```
public class MainModel{
      [Required]        
      public string Foo {get;set;}

      [Required]
      public LocalizedStringModel Bar1 { get;set;}

      // NOT REQUIRED
      public LocalizedStringModel Bar2 { get;set;}

}
```

As you see, two properties of the model class are type of another model class.

```
public class LocalizedStringModel {

      [Required]
      public string DefaultTranslation { get;set;}

      public IList<string> MoreTranslations {get;set;}
}
```

Now the problem is, that because of the RequiredAttribute in the LocalizedStringModel-Class the validation is done for both properties of the MainModel class. Is there a way to do validation only for the required LocalizedStringModel-Property?

I tried implementing a custom RequiredWhenParent-Attribute, but have no access to the parent MainModel-instance from LocalizedStringModel instance. :-(

Someone any idea?

Comment: Much easier (and recommended) would be to use a ViewModel, which would contain all the required by the View properties with data annotation, like `DefaultTranslationBar1`, `DefaultTranslationBar2`, `MoreTranslationsBar1`, `MoreTranslationsBar1` etc.

Comment: Or, you can add another property to LocalizedStringModel say. string DefaultTranslation Required{ get; set; }, rest you already know.

Comment: @Zabavsky But this would result in huge Models and much repetition of code, wouldn't it?

Comment: also, you can validate entire model, with custom model validation.

Comment: A repetition of the code, yes, on the other hand it will result in the overall flexibility and independence between layers. You can use a mapper if a viewmodel becomes complex.

Comment: @Zabavsky what do you exactly mean with mapper? the other problem is, that i use an editortemplate for the localizedstringmodel what would not work if all would be in a huge model.